# How can I change the type of my Haskell function

Tags: haskell, types, polynomials

I have a function that has a type:

```
mulPoly :: Poly -> Poly -> Poly
```

But I want to have a type:

```
mulPoly :: (Num a, Eq a) => Poly a -> Poly a -> Poly a
```

How can I transform this Haskell code:

```
data Poly = [Int] deriving (Show, Eq)

mulPoly :: Poly -> Poly -> Poly
mulPoly (a:as) bs = 
  addPoly (scale a bs) (0 : mulPoly as bs)
```

to this type:

```
data Poly a = P [a] deriving (Show, Eq)

mulPoly :: Poly a -> Poly a -> Poly a
```

here are the functions `addPoly` and `scale` already defined on type `Poly a`

```
addPoly :: (Num a, Eq a) => Poly a -> Poly a -> Poly a
addPoly (P as) (P bs) = P (inner as bs)
  where
    inner [] ys = ys
    inner xs [] = xs
    inner (x:xs) (y:ys) = (x+y) : inner xs ys

scale :: (Num a, Eq a) => a -> Poly a -> Poly a
scale 0 (P (x:xs)) = P []
scale y (P []) = P []
scale y (P (x:xs)) = P (map (y*) (x:xs))
```

Comment: Did you already implmeneted `mulPoly` for `Poly -> Poly -> Poly`?

Comment: yes. It is the first code that I posted

Comment: no, I mean the *implementation* of this function?

Comment: yes I did, but with addPoly :: (Num a, Eq a) => Poly -> Poly -> Poly and scale :: (Num a, Eq a) => a -> Poly  -> Poly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just need to do some wrapping and unwrapping in appropriate places:

```
mulPoly :: (Num a, Eq a) => Poly a -> Poly a -> Poly a
mulPoly (P []) _ = P []   -- you were missing this case
mulPoly (P (a:as)) bs =
    addPoly (scale a bs) 
            (shift1 $ mulPoly (P as) bs)
  where
    shift1 (P bs) = P (0:bs)
```

We just need to pay attention what takes raw lists as arguments, and what takes them wrapped under the `P` tag, and adjust your original code  accordingly.